# How to assign a specific char to a randomly generated position in 2d array? (java)

Tags: java, arrays, random, position

This is the first time I'm using java and I'm supposed to create a game using this program. The 2d array's 10 by 10, 5 specific chars are C,M,W,F and E. There are 15 C,M,W,F each, the remaining 40 boxes are occupied by E. The positions are randomly generated. Any ideas?

Comment: What all you have tried show that then someone will able to help you.Stackoverflow site not for assign your work to someone else.

Comment: I'll give you a hint: first create the array manually and then shuffle it.

Comment: @Harout: that's not efficient. I think I would fill the array with 'E' using Arrays.fill() and then put the other characters in random positions.

Comment: @Adriaan You're right that would be very clever, He can fill the array with 'E' than fill the the first 15 indexes with 'C' and and the second 15 indexes with 'M' so on.. then creating a shuffle method like the one used to shuffle cards he can randomly place them in the array.

Comment: That's not what I meant but I think you are right. Not using a shuffle means retrying random positions until you find a free spot.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to go through the array and fill one of the "C,M,W,F,E" till they are each individually 15 in number.
What you can do is :

```
int randomWithRange(int min, int max)
{
   int range = (max - min) + 1;     
   return (int)(Math.random() * range) + min;
}
```

so you can enter the range as randomWithRange(1,5) and fill the character at specific position. ie: c=1, M=2,W=3....

Once all 15 set is completed for 1 character ignore that and fill with some other char "C,M,W or F". If 15 is completed for all fill with E

You will need to write this logic completely as per your requirement. Reply if you need help. I wont give you code though.

Answer (score 0):

This is a working solution:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Board {

    private List<Character> values = new ArrayList<>();
    private char[][] rows = new char[10][10];
    private int index;

    public void setup() {
        initializeValues();
        fillRows();
    }

    private void initializeValues() {
        add(15, 'C');
        add(15, 'M');
        add(15, 'W');
        add(15, 'F');
        add(40, 'E');
        Collections.shuffle(values);
    }

    private void fillRows() {
        for (int y = 0; y < rows.length; y++) {
            fillRow(rows[y]);
            if (index > values.size()) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void fillRow(char[] row) {
        for (int x = 0; x < row.length; x++) {
            row[x] = values.get(index++);
            if (index > values.size()) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void add(int amount, char value) {
        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
            values.add(value);
        }
    }

    private void print() {
        for (char[] row : rows) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Board board = new Board();
        board.setup();
        board.print();
    }
}
```